# How to add text above table in stargazer package

Tags: r, stargazer

I need help with 2 things:

First I want to set title "Black" to bold

```
stargazer(title = "Black")
```

I want to add a description to the table, just like in the picture, but do not know how to add it in stargazer:

[image]

Comment: In Rmarkdown? To html or pdf?

Comment: The stagazer will give a html output. Regarding Rmarkdown, I do not know what that would mean? Tried googling it, but still dont catch you in this context.

Comment: Stargazer is an outdated package ( 2018-05-30). Maybe you want something other? https://rmarkdown.rstudio.com - ```Rmarkdown```